# Prevent Unity Grid from expanding different windows behind dock in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, compiz, ubuntu-11.10, grid, ubuntu-unity

Is there a way to keep windows in Ubuntu 11.10/Unity from left-docking behind the Unity dock? I want to cut off those pixels entirely and always show the dock, and I want window-resizes to respect this (for maximized and left-docked windows both).

Answer (score 0):

If you set hide to "never", this is default behavior.